# Wrapfigure in Latex does not wrap text (documentclass hepthesis)

Tags: latex, figure, tex

The figure in my thesis does not wrap around the text, instead it goes to the end. Please help?

Here is the code sample:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,bind,ams,a4paper]{hepthesis}

\usepackage{graphicx}   % Including figure files
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
%....
\begin{mainmatter}
\newpage 
\subsection{Stellar classification}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth} 
  \vspace{-20pt}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{img/hydrostatic-equilibrium}%
    \caption{Hydrostatic equilibrium inside stars}
    \label{fig:hydrostatic-equilibrium}
  \end{center}
  \vspace{-20pt}
  \vspace{1pt}
\end{wrapfigure}

Stars are massive gaseos bodies which generate energy through nuclear fusion in the core, and release it as radiation. The mass of the star determines the star's proerties (such as temperature, luminosity and size), but most importantly its evolution track. The pressure of the energy emitted from the core would cause the star to explode, were it not counteracted by the gravity of the surrounding material. When the two forces are in equilibrium (Figure \ref{fig:hydrostatic-equilibrium}), also called hydrostatic equilibrium, the star is stable. When the balance changes, however, so does the state of the star. The Sun is an example of a main-sequence star, which has been fusing hydrogen into Helium for 5 billions years, and is predicted to do so for 5 billion more. 

The Sun is an example of a main-sequence star, which has been fusing hydrogen into Helium for 5 billions years, and is predicted to do so for 5 billion more. The Sun is an example of a main-sequence star, which has been fusing hydrogen into Helium for 5 billions years, and is predicted to do so for 5 billion more. The Sun is an example of a main-sequence star, which has been fusing hydrogen into Helium for 5 billions years, and is predicted to do so for 5 billion more.  
\end{mainmatter}
\end{document}
```

[image: Final pdf]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Please make sure to post a [mcve]. Your document does not compile out of the box (missing `\end{document}`, ...).

Comment: Thanks! Ok there is an \begin{mainmatter} \end{mainmatter} around the body of the thesis that seems to cause the problems. I have this template from the university, and am no expert in latex, but I think this is purely for code management, I can remove them, right? Are wrap figures allowed in the thesis anyway? :-?

Comment: I would replace `\begin{mainmatter}` by `\mainmatter` and remove `\end{mainmatter}`, c.f. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Book_structure